# How to pass localhost address to Tyk target URL?

Tags: docker, tyk

I have my Tyk components (Tyk Pro Demo from GitHub) running using Docker compose. When I create a simple API using some public APIs, like Pet Store Io, it works fine.

Now I have word press application running using Docker compose, and the Docker compose file is available here (https://docs.docker.com/samples/wordpress/). This application is running on http://localhost:8000.

However, when I pass this 'localhost:8000' to the target URL in Tyk API definition, and call it through Tyk, it show 'There was a problem proxying the request'.

Is there any setting/ method which can solve this problem?

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I tried already. But doesn't work.

Comment: can you make sure both of them are running in the same docker network?

Comment: Hi @Jeffy Mathew. Yes. Actually I found that I have to make sure they are at the same Docker network, and then it will be working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when I referred to Docker documentation, I realized that I just need to put them in the same Docker network and it will be done.